# How to show that $f(x)\equiv x$ for an injective and continuous $ f $ satisfying $f\big(2x-f(x)\big)\equiv x$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a bijective function with a fixed point $a$. i.e. $f(a)=a$. Suppose $f$ satisfies the following relation
> $$f\big(2x-f(x)\big)=x \text,\qquad \forall x\in \mathbb R \text.$$
> Then how can I show that $f(x)\equiv x$?
>
> **Additional question:** what about if $f$ is **injective and continuous**?

I saw a bit long solution of this before somewhere (I don't know where). I am looking for a beautiful solution.

**Edit:** I think one can work on the following way for solution:

Suppose there exist a $b$ such that $f(b)\ne b$. Then the set
$$K:=\{b,f(b),f\circ f(b), \dots \}$$
is a infinite set of distinct points. I have no Idea how to use this!

Comment: Please show us some more context.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891116/if-f2x-fx-x-find-all-bijective-functions

Comment: Changing your question drastically after receiving multiple answers is considered rude here. If you don't want to ask a new question, you may add a second part to your question with the new conditions, and keep the old question intact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is false.  To construct a counterexample, let us first see what the functional equation says about a single orbit of $f$.  Applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides and substituting $y=f^{-1}(x)$, the functional equation is equivalent to $2f(y)-f(f(y))=y$ or $$f(f(y))=2f(y)-y.$$  Now fix some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and write $x_n=f^n(x)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  The functional equation is then equivalent to saying that every such orbit $(x_n)$ satisfies the linear recurrence $$x_{n+2}=2x_{n+1}-x_n.$$ The solutions to this recurrence are just $x_n=cn+d$ for constants $c$ and $d$.  Or, since $d$ must be $x_0=x$, given our initial point $x$ we can take any sequence of the form $x_n=cn+x$.

So to construct a counterexample, we just have to construct a bijection whose orbits all have this form.  That is easy by transfinite recursion: if we've already defined $f$ on a set of orbits of size less than $\mathfrak{c}$, we can extend $f$ to one more point $x$ by picking $c$ so that the orbit $\{cn+x:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ of $x$ will not intersect any of the orbits we have chosen so far.  So, building $f$ one orbit at a time like this by transfinite recursion (starting from a single orbit that gives $f$ a fixed point), we can build $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ different solutions (since we have more than one choice of $c$ that works at each step).

---

On the other hand, it is true if you assume $f$ is continuous and injective instead of bijective.  First, note that injectivity implies bijectivity, since the functional equation immediately implies $f$ is surjective.  Now suppose $f$ is additionally continuous and $f(x)\neq x$ for some $x$.  By the analysis above, $f^n(x)$ must have the form $cn+x$ for some constant $c$, and $c\neq 0$ since $f(x)\neq x$.  Now there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the fixed point $a$ is between $cn+x$ and $c(n+1)+x$.  Let us assume for convenience of notation that $c>0$; the case $c<0$ is similar.  We then have $$cn+x<a$$ but $$f(a)=a<c(n+1)+x=f(cn+x),$$ which means $f$ must be decreasing (it must be monotone since it is a continuous bijection).  But $$x<c+x$$ and $$f(x)=c+x<2c+x=f(c+x)$$ so $f$ must be increasing.  This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

As Eric Wofsey wrote in his comment, the statement as it stands is false. Here is a counterexample. Let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&x\in\mathbb Z;\\
x-1,&x\not\in\mathbb Z.\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is bijective, it has a fixed point (any integer will do) and
$$f(2x-f(x))=\begin{cases}f(2x-x)=f(x)=x,&x\in\mathbb Z;\\
f(2x-(x-1))=f(x+1)=x,&x\not\in\mathbb Z.\end{cases}$$
However, the statement is true if both the domain and codomain of $f$ are equal to some bounded set $S$. See the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891116/594946) mentioned by Tsemo Aristide in another comment.